# why can't orbit control work with a sphere instead of camera in three js?

Tags: three.js

I want to spin a sphere, so I wonder if orbit controls could work for that.

However, code below won't work:

```
var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(16, 16, 16);
var material  = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
var mesh  = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( mesh );

var controls  = new THREE.OrbitControls(mesh);
//then inside the animation loop
controls.update();
```

It seems like orbit controls only works when argument is camera. why?

Comment: Because OrbitControls is meant to work on Cameras,.... Update your question and explain what you are trying to achieve and we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the camera to the Orbit.

Like this:

```
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
            camera.position.set( 0, 1000, 1000 );

            var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
```

This helps?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think orbit controls work like that, the camera revolves around a point, it doesn't 'spin' that point. You can however change the target of the orbit controls to the sphere's position vector, allowing the camera to revolve around the sphere's position:

```
controls.target.copy(mesh.position);
```